# Android: Cannot access public static function or public variables from another class

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

Here is the declaration in 'MainActivity.java'

```
private static String competition = null;
```

I've created a setter function which adds value to it.

```
public static void setCompetition(String competition1) {
    competition = competition1;
}
```

I've created a getter function to get the value in another class from the same package:

```
public static String getCompetition() {
    return competition;
}
```

However it returns null.

Here is how I tried to use it in a function 
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

with in the class AlarmNotify which extends BroadcastReceiver:

```
       final String competition = MainActivity.getCompetition();
```

Comment: Well presumably you haven't called `setCompetition` with a non-null value anywhere...

Comment: Have you checked if the activity is still in memory while doing that call ?

Comment: And show the code, where you setting competition String. Also it will be more clear to see `this.` before acces to class global statements

Comment: Where are you calling `MainActivity.setCompetition()`?

Comment: I'm calling setCompetition in an Async method - MainActivity.setCompetition(json.getString(MainActivity.TAG_COMPETITION));
   

I can see the output of that into a textview

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not invoking `setCompetition` anywhere. To validate that, try with this piece of code -

```
public static void setCompetition(String competition1) {
    System.out.println("Set competition to "+competition1);
    competition = competition1;
}
```

If you do not see any printed message, then `setCompetition` is not being invoked. Ensure that this is being invoked.

Comment: I'm calling setCompetition in an Async method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mistake I did:
I was calling a network based async task, which takes few seconds to retrieve the data. It works in the background.

I was calling another function which was trying to access these values. It was being fired instantaneously, even before the async task could run. That is why it was returning null.

Async task hadn't returned those values.

Ultimately I put the call to the other function in the postExecute method of the Async.

Hope that helps anyone who makes the same mistake as I did.